# Bundle Install command won't install my gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian

Okay, so I'm very new to Rails, and am just beginning to feel my way around my new Linux operating system as well.

I'm currently doing a project for school, and I've followed all of the directions to perfection. For consistency purposes, they want specific versions of both rails and gemsets.

After I have initialized rails in my directory, I then run a 
`bundle install` command, and have several installation issues which I are in the code block as follows:

```
user@user-ThinkPad-T430 ~/code/bloccit $ sudo bundle install
[sudo] password for user: 
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, 
and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
non-root users on this machine.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-
1.8.6/ext/json/ext/generator
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171128-11271-1ah858h.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-1.8.6 
for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-
linux/2.3.0/json-1.8.6/gem_make.out
Using minitest 5.10.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using crass 1.0.3
Using rack 1.6.8
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using arel 6.0.4
Using bundler 1.11.2
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Installing ffi 1.9.18 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171128-11271-1382ks7.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 
for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-
linux/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
Installing pg 0.21.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171128-11271-171n79p.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0 
for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-
linux/2.3.0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make.out
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2
Using tilt 2.0.8
Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171128-11271-ml1ggl.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at 
/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-
1.3.13 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-
linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using i18n 0.9.1
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.6), and Bundler cannot 
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The main error seems to be the `Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` line, but it's also having problems installing json within the bundler.

Any helpful advice or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all follow the instruction (please avoid `sudo`):

> Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, 
>   and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all
>   non-root users on this machine.

To resolve this issue in `linux`, run:

```
sudo apt install ruby2.3-dev
```

Cheers!